# Cypress doesn't fail on TypeScript compilation error

Tags: typescript, cypress

I've created a new Cypress project, run `yarn run cypress open`, added `tsconfig.json` as described in https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support, changed the extension of `integration/1-getting-started/todo.spec.js` to `.ts`. I can run the tests and see TS errors in VS Code. The problem is that even if TS code definitely has errors, the tests still run (and can pass!). I've tried adding `"noEmitOnError": true` to `"compilerOptions"`, but this doesn't seem to have an effect (perhaps it's using previously emitted files?).

If I run `npx tsc` manually, I get not just the expected errors in my own code (the last one), but also some errors in `cypress types`:

```
alexey@DESKTOP-41AVESA:~/shaka/popmenu/spec/cypress-ts$ npx tsc 
../../node_modules/cypress/types/cy-blob-util.d.ts:6:27 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'blob-util'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

6 import * as blobUtil from 'blob-util'
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/cypress/types/cy-bluebird.d.ts:4:35 - error TS2792: Cannot find module './bluebird'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

4 import ImportedBluebird = require('./bluebird')
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/cypress/types/cypress-eventemitter.d.ts:2:29 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'eventemitter2'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

2 type EventEmitter2 = import("eventemitter2").EventEmitter2
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/cypress/types/cypress-eventemitter.d.ts:33:33 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'buffer/'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

33 type BufferType = typeof import("buffer/").Buffer
                                   ~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/cypress/types/sinon-chai/index.d.ts:12:24 - error TS2792: Cannot find module '../sinon'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

12 import * as Sinon from '../sinon';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~

cypress/integration/1-getting-started/todo.spec.ts:14:7 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

14 const message: number = "Hello World"
         ~~~~~~~
```

Cypress version: 9.5.4
TypeScript version: 4.6.3

Comment: Why exactly is this a problem? You are not motivated to fix the type errors shown in VSCode?

Comment: I am. But I'd still prefer tests to fail in CI.

Comment: Cypress cannot run Typescript, only Javascript.

Comment: @CarlSerrander No, I didn't.